# Seperating 2 phones?

Tags: software-update, iphone

With the new update how do I keep my 2 iphones separate one is for work and the other is a personal phone? I don't want to receive work messages and calls on my personal phone and vice versa. And I don't want to create another Apple ID.

Comment: Why do you think updating to iOS9 will change your current setup?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to receive work messages and calls on my personal phone and vice versa. And I don't want to create another Apple ID.

These two things cannot occur simultaneously. If you want to separate the devices completely, you'll need two Apple IDs. Once you have two Apple IDs, the devices are essentially separate.